# OpenCV claims to find "wrong" cuda version

Tags: opencv, cmake, cuda

I build OpenCV 3.4. with Cuda 10.0 support in "/usr"local/opencv_custom" like this:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE 
-D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/opencv_custom
-D OPENCV_GENERATE_PKGCONFIG=ON
-D OPENCV_DNN_CUDA=ON
-D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON
-D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON
-D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/home/ohmnibot/opencv_contrib/modules
-D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON
-D BUILD_opencv_python2=OFF
-D WITH_FFMPEG=1
-D WITH_CUDA=ON
-D WITH_OPENGL=ON
-D ENABLE_FAST_MATH=1
-D CUDA_FAST_MATH=1
-D WITH_CUBLAS=0
-D WITH_LAPACK=OFF
-D BUILD_opencv_cudacodec=OFF
-D CUDA_VERSION=10.0 ..
```

All is fine but when I try to include this opencv version in my CMakeList like this

```
set(OpenCV_DIR "/usr/local/opencv_custom")
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
```

I get this error:

```
Could NOT find CUDA: Found unsuitable version "10.2", but required is exact
  version "10.0" (found /usr/local/cuda-10.0)
```

Now I had cuda 10.2 installed but I removed every possible trace of it and only cuda 10.0 exists on my system (as far as I know).
Also I just don´t get this message.... cuda 10.0 has been found but its unsuitable because its the wrong version even though... well its the right one?

I don´t know this just confuses the hell out of me... any help is deeply appreciated.

I´m working with catkin on a Ubuntu 18.04 system with a GTX 1650.

Old cuda versions have been removed with

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove "*cublas*" "cuda*" "nsight*"
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/cuda*
```

nvcc -V output:

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2018 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sat_Aug_25_21:08:01_CDT_2018
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.0, V10.0.130
```

nvidia-smi output:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 450.66       Driver Version: 450.66       CUDA Version: 11.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1650    Off  | 00000000:07:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 35%   29C    P8     8W /  75W |    447MiB /  3908MiB |      3%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

Comment: What is ur OS? What is your gpu ?

Comment: OS is Ubuntu 18.04, GPU is GTX 1650

Comment: "but I deleted every possible trace of it " -- plainly you didn't

Comment: Deleting files not a safe way why you not uninstall as like installed ? What is your driver version ?

Comment: I didn mean that I just deleted the files.... I uninstalled it using sudo apt-get --purge remove "*cublas*" "cuda*" "nsight*" and sudo rm -rf /usr/local/cuda* and then installed cuda on what I thought would be a clean sytem

driver version is 450.66

Comment: @talonmies well I searched around a bit and according to stackoverflow the method I used should do the trick... if not what should I do to get rid of the rest? Or rather what is even left?

Comment: Search your filesystem thoroughly. Then make sure this isn't just CMake caching an old failed build

Comment: yeez... so I´m working with catkin and the error message changed after I deleted everything and installed cuda, tensorrt etc from scratch so I didn´t thing that it could be a caching problem but it was... after building from scratch it worked like a charm.

I´m so mad at myself right now, this took way too long to figure out :D

And your profile description is very accurate... sorry for adding one more rather stupid question to your list :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in case someone every manages to run into a similar error:

- delete all the build files
- rebuild
- enjoy

Answer (score 0):

I have ran into this problem a few times. The accepted answer has worked for me a few times but not always. I think adding the following brings value to anyone who has similar problems.

---

### Check the values of variables `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

You can check the value like this:

```
echo ${PATH}
echo ${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
```

I had the wrong CUDA version there and I corrected it using a text editor like this:

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

Search for `PATH` (using `nano` press ctrl+W to find). I had these at the very bottom:

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/cuda-11.8/bin
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda-11.8/lib64
```

and surprisingly I had wrong CUDA version there. I corrected it using text editor to what I wanted (in my case 11.6).

Note that this only changes the variables. You must check that you really have the right version of CUDA at `/usr/local/cuda-*` and that your `/usr/local/cuda` is pointing to the right place. We will check that next:

---

### Check that `cuda` points to the correct version

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40041463/opencv-3-1-0-finds-cuda-7-5-instead-of-8-0),

```
cd /usr/local
ls -l | grep cuda
```

then see which versions of CUDA you see there. For me I have only one but I used to have many

```
/usr/local$ ls -l | grep cuda
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    21 tammi  10 15:15 cuda -> /usr/local/cuda-11.6/
drwxr-xr-x 16 root root  4096 tammi  10 15:16 cuda-11.6
```

that hints that I don't have any conflicting CUDA installations. But you might have that if you have several versions installed.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45477133/how-to-change-cuda-version) answer might be helpful, too.

---

### Check that OpenCV is searching for the correct version

when you're running the configuration step of OpenCV build, check that the `-D CUDA_VERSION` is right:

```
cd build-opencv
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D WITH_TBB=ON -D ENABLE_FAST_MATH=1 -D CUDA_FAST_MATH=1 -D CUDA_GENERATION=AUTO -D WITH_CUBLAS=1 -D WITH_CUDA=ON -D BUILD_opencv_cudacodec=OFF -D WITH_CUDNN=ON -D OPENCV_DNN_CUDA=ON -D CUDA_ARCH_BIN=8.6 -D CUDA_GENERATION=Auto -D WITH_V4L=ON -D WITH_QT=OFF -D WITH_OPENGL=OFF -D WITH_GSTREAMER=ON -D OPENCV_GENERATE_PKGCONFIG=ON -D OPENCV_PC_FILE_NAME=opencv.pc -D OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../opencv_contrib-4.x/modules ../opencv-4.x -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=OFF -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF -D CUDA_VERSION=11.6 -D CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS="-ccbin gcc-8"
```

then, double check that the prints after this command are what you expect and possibly save them to a text file. They are really helpful:

```
-- CUDA detected: 11.6
-- CUDA NVCC target flags: -ccbin gcc-8;-gencode;arch=compute_86,code=sm_86;-D_FORCE_INLINES

(skipping many other lines...)

--   NVIDIA CUDA:                   YES (ver 11.6, CUFFT CUBLAS FAST_MATH)
--     NVIDIA GPU arch:             86
--     NVIDIA PTX archs:
-- 
--   cuDNN:                         YES (ver 8.7.0)
--
```

---

### Add `-D CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR`

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46514864/cmake-cannot-find-newer-cuda-package) answer and [this thread](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/16333) might be outdated but if nothing else helps you it doesn't hurt to check them.

---

### Check that you really made a clean build

I rebuilt my OpenCV a couple of times but it didn't really help. The reason might be that I didn't remove all OpenCV -related files.

```
sudo make uninstall
```

as well as removing associated files:

```
sudo rm -r /usr/local/include/opencv2 /usr/local/include/opencv /usr/include/opencv /usr/include/opencv2 /usr/local/share/opencv /usr/local/share/OpenCV /usr/share/opencv /usr/share/OpenCV /usr/local/bin/opencv* /usr/local/lib/libopencv*
```

If you want to be super careful, please also check the output of this

```
sudo find / -name "*opencv*"
```

as different versions of OpenCV might have different install directories.

### Other

Then, you also have the option of uninstalling OpenCV, removing all build files, uninstalling CUDA and starting from scratch. Make sure you follow [the CUDA installation guides](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/index.html#installation-guides) carefully and perform all pre- and post-installation steps. In addition, make sure you have followed all installation steps of OpenCV [here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html), [here](https://developer.ridgerun.com/wiki/index.php/Compiling_OpenCV_from_Source) and [here](https://gist.github.com/Mahedi-61/804a663b449e4cdb31b5fea96bb9d561). Please check the output of all steps for errors that might have been left unseen earlier.

Remember to make a clean build of your application after reinstalling CUDA and OpenCV as well as restarting your PC and/or refreshing your environment variables.